# How to get attribute inside a tag in Javascript for sorting function

Tags: javascript, sorting, appendchild

i found this function which is working good but i need something a little more specific:

```
    function sortList() {
  var ul = document.getElementsByClassName("myUL")[0];
    
  Array.from(ul.getElementsByTagName("li"))
    .sort((a, b) => a.getAttribute('title').localeCompare(b.getAttribute('title')))
    .forEach(li => ul.appendChild(li));
}
```

So, i need to getAttribute title but from img tag which is inside my li instead of the li itself and i don't know ho to do this. Sorry for the stupid question but i'm a total noob just trying to create a simple archive for personal use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Element.closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

```
   function sortList() {
      var ul = document.getElementsByClassName("myUL")[0];
      Array.from(ul.getElementsByTagName("li"))
        .sort((a, b) => a.querySelector("img").getAttribute('title').localeCompare(b.querySelector("img").getAttribute('title')))
        .forEach(li => ul.appendChild(li));
    }
```

Comment: @Teemu. Right. Thanks

Comment: Works like a charm, I wonder why the function only affects the first UL on my page though. I have like 4 list with same class, actually i used class instead of id for that reason but no luck.

Comment: `var ul = document.getElementsByClassName("myUL")[0];` Here we are only getting first ul. I. e at first position  0